# Magento 2 API, catalog price rule is not applied

Tags: magento2

The catalog price rule is working in frontend. But when we get the product from REST API, we are getting the original price only.

Example:
Product price is 34, we were created catalog rule with 10% for all products, in frontend we are getting both prices 30.26 and 34. But from api, we are getting only 34.

Please help.

**API EndPoint:**

> http://localhost/magento/rest/default/V1/products/24-MB01

```
Partial Response:
{
  "id": 1,
  "sku": "24-MB01",
  "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
  "attribute_set_id": 15,
  "price": 34,
  "status": 1,
  "visibility": 4,
  "type_id": "simple",
  "created_at": "2017-01-10 07:50:47",
  "updated_at": "2017-01-10 07:50:47",
  "extension_attributes": [],
  "product_links": [],
  "options": [],
}
```

Comment: share your parametrs and rest api call code. Post code

Comment: Hi @ManthanDave, Please check the edited content.

Comment: So sad that magento api does not support catalog price rules. We are not able to show real product prices in mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Special Price is a custom attributes so you will get its details response in **Custom Attributes** section.

So follow below steps :

1. Your Api end point should be - http://yourwebsitelink/index.php/rest/default/V1/products/24-MB01/
2. Pass Authorization Bearer your_access_token in the header
3. You will get the full response wit details of that product :
4. So over there at last you will find option "**custom_attributes**" like below :

> ```
> "tier_prices": [],
>   "custom_attributes": [
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "description",
>       "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "special_price",
>       "value": "30.0000"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "special_from_date",
>       "value": "2017-02-07 00:00:00"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "special_to_date",
>       "value": "2017-02-28 00:00:00"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "cost",
>       "value": "30.0000"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "image",
>       "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "small_image",
>       "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
>       "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "color",
>       "value": "49"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "news_from_date",
>       "value": "2017-02-15 00:00:00"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "custom_design_from",
>       "value": "2017-02-15 00:00:00"
>     },
>     {
>       "attribute_code": "category_ids",
>       "value": [
>         "3",
>         "4"
>       ]
>     },
> ```

5. From there you will get **attribute_code = special_price and its value**

Comment: Thank you Manthan. But I'm not getting the special_price attribute in my custom attributes.

Comment: Hi @ManthanDave, Any solution?

Comment: @Nagarajan i have check with my end II Yes its not working and there is no solution for catalog price rules !! see this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801856/how-to-retrieve-magento-catalog-prices-rules-with-magento-api